# Web-scraping across multiple links using R

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I'm attempting to create a tidy dataframe of some news releases for several websites. Most of the websites are structured so that there is a main page of headlines with a short blurb, then a link to the main article. I'd like to scrape all of the main articles from the main page. Here's my approach. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(xml2)

url_1 <- read_html("http://lifepointhealth.net/news")


## seems to grab the lists
url_1 %>% 
  html_nodes("li") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_squish() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  enframe()

# A tibble: 80 x 2
    name value                      
   <int> <chr>                      
 1     1 Who We Are Our Company Mis…
 2     2 Our Company Mission, Visio…
 3     3 Mission, Vision, Values an…
 4     4 Giving Quality a Voice     
 5     5 How We Operate             
 6     6 Leadership                 
 7     7 Awards                     
 8     8 20th Anniversary           
 9     9 Our Communities Explore Ou…
10    10 Explore Our Communities    
# … with 70 more rows


# this grabs the titles but there should be many more
url_1 %>% 
  html_nodes("li .title") %>% 
  html_text() %>% 
  str_squish() %>% 
  str_trim() %>% 
  enframe() 

# A tibble: 20 x 2
    name value                      
   <int> <chr>                      
 1     1 LifePoint Health Names Elm…
 2     2 David Steitz Named Chief E…
 3     3 LifePoint Health Receives …
 4     4 Thousands of Top U.S. Hosp…
 5     5 Conemaugh Nason Medical Ce…
 6     6 Vicki Parks Named CEO of W…
 7     7 LifePoint Health Honors Ka…
 8     8 Ennis Regional Medical Cen…
 9     9 LifePoint Health Business …
10    10 LifePoint Health and R1 RC…
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the Network tab of Dev Tool, you will see the page sends requests to `http://lifepointhealth.net/api/posts` each time you click "Load more". Imitate the request like below, you will be able to scrape all 332 post details:

```
items <- httr::POST(
  "http://lifepointhealth.net/api/posts",
  config = httr::add_headers(`Content-Type` = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"),
  body = "skip=0&take=332&Type=News&tagFilter=",
  encode = "multipart"
) %>% 
  httr::content() %>%
  .$Items

items <- dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(items, function(f) {
  as.data.frame(Filter(Negate(is.null), f))
}))
```